# How to add actions in controller of third party module in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using ZfcUser module. I have seen the wiki and [here](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-override-built-in-view-scripts) i have find out how to override views of existing actions in controllers of ZfcUser. My question is, how to add another action for e.g. `changeDisplayPictureAction()`.

The approach I used was to create a custom module, configure out `module.config.php` this way

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser' => 'MyNamespace\Controller\UserController',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I also extended `UserController` with `ZfcUser\Controller\UserController`but because I created new actions in it along with new views. There is no way to point parent-class actions to views they already have in parent module. In other words, I have to copy all views in module where the child or final class exists. Otherwise I am getting this error message

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "my-user/profile/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

All I want to do is add some new actions in third party modules without disturbing them but extending them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to change existing functionality, why extend it? Just create a new Controller and have your route configured correctly so it dispatches your new actions towards the new controller and let the existing controller handle the existing actions.

`return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
             'myuser' => 'MyNamespace\Controller\UserController,
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'myuser' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/user/change-display-picture',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'myuser',
                        'action' => 'change-display-picture',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);`